# I had an issue with bootstrap's datetime picker on MozilaFirefox

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello guys I had an issue with datetimepicker on FF. In other browsers its doing good with the code I wrote. The problem is I have three drop down options. In each one I had, time is inserted by the user using datetimepicker but unfortunately the picker works only on one of the three of them. Any idea why this is happening

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
echo '<div class="table-rsponsive overlap">';
echo '<table class="table" >';
$workingDaysNum = array();
$counter = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($j = 0; $j < 7/* count($spec) */; $j++) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            echo '<td>' . $days[$j] . '</td>';
        } else {
            $counter++;
            $workingDaysNum[] = 'datetimepicker' . $counter;
            ?>
            <td>

                <div class="input-group date datetimepicker" id="<?php echo $workingDaysNum[$counter - 1] ?>">
                    <input  class="form-control " id="filter-date" size="16" type="text" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>

            <?php
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
$(function () {
<?php
foreach ($workingDaysNum as $workDay) {
    echo '$(' . $workDay . ').datetimepicker({';
    echo 'format: \'HH:mm\',';
    echo 'stepping: 30';
    echo '});';
}
?>

<?php
foreach ($workingDaysNum as $workDay) {
    echo '$("' . $workDay . '").on("dp.change",function (e) {';
    echo 'saveSpec1Modal("' . $workDay . '", $("' . $workDay . '").data(\'date\'))';
//echo 'console.log($("#'.$workDay.'").data(\'date\'))';
    echo '});';
}
?>

    });
```

Comment: what is $days? It's undefined when i try and run this code (obviously)

Comment: $days is containing the days of the week Monday, Tuesday...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditch the loops in the jQuery.

Instead of activating datetimepicker by *ID*, you have already given them all a *class*, so you can run it once instead of looping.

```
$(function () {
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'HH:mm',
        stepping: 30
    });
});
```

Same applies to the change function.

Comment: Nope the problem remains the first drop down is getting the time values but the other two are not clickable and the datetimepicker drop down is not showing

Comment: just read your comment but also notice you marked this as correct? how did you get on?

Comment: It helped but not in the way I wanted so i'm searching for a different decision on the problem. So i'm open for more :)